# Validate XML data with XSD without Soap Envelope

Tags: java, xml, xslt, soap, xsd

I have XML data with SOAP Envelope but my XSD schemas can only validate XML data inside the envelope. I am looking forward to the mechanism in which i can edit XSD and traverse and only validate the xml which is inside the envelope.

Like for example, in XSLT we get option to set the root parameter `<xsl:template match="*:MsgHeader">` rather than `<xsl:template match="*:Envelope">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggest, doing the validation in XSLT (2.0+) is one option - but probably not a very good one, because XSLT stops after the first validation error.

If you use Saxon as your validation engine then you can do the required validation from Java like this:

```
Processor p = new Processor(true);
SchemaManager sm = p.getSchemaManager();
sm.load(new StreamSource(new File('schema.xsd')));
SchemaValidator sv = sm.newSchemaValidator();
DocumentBuilder db = p.newDocumentBuilder();
XdmNode doc = db.build(new StreamSource(new File('source.xml')));
XdmNode target = (XdmNode)doc.select(descendant("payload")).findFirst().get();
sv.validate(target.asSource());
```

Comment: Yes, solution sounds good. But i was hoping to do min/no change in the code and solve it using just XSD files(since some xml might not have that req). If you can suggest any mechanism that can be used to bypass the SOAP envelope by making changes in XSD itself would be really great. Thankyou again for speedy response and code changes.

Comment: Can't you just add a schema for the SOAP envelope namespace to the mix?

Comment: Yes, not exactly importing the SOAP envelope, I solved it by creating another xsd with the schema defined [here](https://github.com/strongloop/strong-soap/blob/master/xsds/soap-envelope.xsd) and then imported my main xsd by replacing on line no 62. Thankyou for your help